# Unable to get confirm box when user Refreshes/Reloads page in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webbrowser-control, page-refresh

I am building an angular 4 app, and i want to implement `a confirm box` which will be shown, only when the user is pressing the page refresh or does page reload. The confirm box should be something like [image: this]

I have used the same code as it is in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lda61q3d/119/).
In jsfiddle, the functionality is working fine, but in my angular app, it is not working.
If i put any `console.log` inside the function, then i am able to get the output in console, as soon as i refresh the page, but this doesnt stop the page from reloading.

Any suggestion whats wrong here!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) says:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

You should use the `returnValue` property in addition to the `return` keyword.

Comment: Works like a Charm! Thanks mate, this is what i needed. @nesk